# Serialize Specialized List<>

Tags: c#, generics, serialization

I have a specialized class, BusinessObjectList, with this declaration:

```
public class BusinessObjectList<T> : List<BusinessObject> where T: BusinessObject {}
```

And I want to serialize objects of this class, like:

```
info.AddValue("myList", myList);
```

I tried to add the interface ISerializable, but with no success.

```
public class BusinessObjectList<T> : List<BusinessObject>, ISerializable where T: BusinessObject {}
```

The list is always null when unserialized.
I think List<> objects are serializable, but what about subclasses of them?

EDIT:

Just for future reference, here is the entire class:

BusinessObjectList.cs (When you call save(), it automatically persists on DB all inserts and removes from the list, and also saves all modified values on the business objects):

```
[Serializable()]
public class BusinessObjectList<T> : List<BusinessObject>,ISerializable where T: BusinessObject
{
    public delegate void BusinessObjectListDeleteHandler(T objDeleted);
    public event BusinessObjectListDeleteHandler deleteHandler;

    List<BusinessObject> objsForDelete = new List<BusinessObject>();
    public BusinessObjectList()
    {

    }

    public new void Add(BusinessObject item)
    {
        base.Add(item);
    }
    public new T this[int index]
    {
        get
        {                 
            return (T)base[index];
        }
    }

    public bool save()
    {
        foreach (T obj in objsForDelete)
        {
            if (deleteHandler != null)
                deleteHandler(obj);
            obj.delete();
        }
        objsForDelete.Clear();
        foreach (BusinessObject obj in this)
        {
            obj.save();
        }
        return true;
    }

    public new void Clear()
    {
        foreach (BusinessObject obj in this)
        {
            //obj.delete();
            objsForDelete.Add(obj);
        }
        base.Clear();
    }

    public new void Remove(BusinessObject obj)
    {
        // obj.delete();
        objsForDelete.Add(obj);
        base.Remove(obj);
    }

    public new void RemoveAt(int index)
    {
        objsForDelete.Add(this[index]);
        base.RemoveAt(index);
    }


    #region ISerializable Members

    public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        // should I do something here??
    }

    #endregion
}
```

And BusinessObject.cs:

```
[Serializable()]
public abstract class BusinessObject:ISerializable
{
    public abstract bool save();
    public abstract bool delete();
    public abstract DbTransaction startTransaction();
    public abstract void useTransaction(DbTransaction transaction);
    public abstract DbTransaction getTransaction();

    #region ISerializable Members

    public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {            
        // nothing to serialize here            
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: Personally, I'm of the opinion that there are many good reasons simply not to use `BinaryFormatter` here; especially if you intend to save the data - a contract based approach such as `XmlSerializer` would be far more stable.

Comment: I need to serialize it because my sessions on IIS are being stored on SQL Server, instead of in-proc. Is it possible to use XMLSerializer for that purpose?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you should inherit from [`System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132397.aspx), not `List<BusinessObject>`.  It's better to inherit from `Collection<T>` so that you can have control over all changes to the list (even changes made through `IList<T>`) by overriding InsertItem, SetItem, etc.  It's probably also better to inherit from a collection of `T` than a collection of `BusinessObject` so that the methods and indexer you inherit from your base class use the correct type.

To answer your question, none of the .Net collection types (including `Collection<T>`) are serializable.  You'll need to serialize and deserialize the collection yourself; see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty01x675%28VS.85%29.aspx) for instructions.

Comment: Thank you, I am already doing this serializing for all my business objects, but I thought List<T> were serializable by default.

And I am going to inherit from Collection<T> from now on. Thanks.